# Add a muted audio stream inside a filter_complex

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there some way to have the same effect as the code below but inside a `-filter_complex`? So I can avoid to run two different commands to do what I need to.

```bsh
ffmpeg \
-f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 \
-i media.mov \
-c:v copy \
-c:a aac \
-shortest \
output.mov
```

**What the code above does?**
Adds an audio stream muted to a video.

**Why do I need to do that?**
Because this video is inputed by users of my system and I never know if the video inputed have or not an audio stream. After that I gonna concat this video with another one and the command concat on ffmpeg requires all input media to have the same number of streams [as you can see here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#:%7E:text=All%20segments%20must%20have%20the%20same%20number%20of%20streams%20of%20each%20type).

Comment: What is it you need to *"to do what I need to"*? Currently, this comes across as an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Ok, I'm adding an explanation in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
ffmpeg \
-i media.mov \
-filter_complex "anullsrc=r=44100:cl=stereo[a]" \
-map 0:0 -map "[a]" \
-c:v copy \
-c:a aac \
-shortest \
output.mov
```

see [anullsrc filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc), and [Stream-selection -map](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection)